# Why can't I access my amazon RDS instance from my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

So I created an RDS instance in asia pacific(Mumbai) region and separately created an EC2 instance in the same region. My local machine can access the DB server just fine but it is not accessible from within my EC2 instance.
I took my EC2's public IPv4 address:
[image]
And put this instance ip in the inbound rules for the security group for my rds instance:
[image]
Unfortunately this did not work. Lucky for me, exposing all ips works for me:
[image] Even if it does work, exposing all ips is not what I want. Am I missing something? How can I enable my RDS to only be accessible from the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the public IP of the EC2 instance to the RDS security group. Since the EC2 instance and RDS instance are in the same VPC, communication between them would happen entirely within the VPC. This means you need to whitelist the Pivate IP of the EC2 instance, not the Public IP. The Public IP would only be used when the EC2 instance sends a request outside the VPC.

I would actually recommend whitelisting the security group ID that the EC2 instance belongs to, instead of the EC2 instance's specific IP address. This will allow the security group to keep working if the EC2 instance's IP changes, or if you you scale out your application to multiple EC2 instances.

Answer (score 2):

Just Adding to @Mark answer, If your ec2 instance and RDS in the same VPC then private IP should work, but if in different VPC then you have to add the public IP address, but in your case public not working so its mean both are in the same VPC.

One way is to allow Security group ID of EC2 instance against `3306` as @Mark mentioned,

But the other way can be,

For example, if your VPC CIDR block was 10.0.0.0/16, then:

I will suggest allowing `10.0.0.0/16` against `3306` port in the DB security group this will allow all EC2 instances, will help to test and debugging.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the "Public accessibility" to "Yes" from the database settings.

Comment: That has no bearing on accessing it from within the same VPC.